# preciso juntar vários links em 1 único link que quando a pessoa clique direcione ordenadamente

Tags: url, paginação, redirecionamento-de-url, google-sites

eu clonei uma página de vendas(com permissão) e agora precisa consolidar todos os links das diferentes páginas clonadas em um único link que direcione ordenadamente para todas as outras páginas. Isso permitirá que, quando o lead clique nesse único link, seja direcionado automaticamente para todas as outras páginas.

eu já tentei para juntar os links em 1 só criar uma página básica de html mas não tenho muito conhecimento, então não deu certo.
já tentei pesquisar e falar com IA mas elas me direcionaram a criar uma página de html.
Tentei colocar todos os links dessas páginas clonadas no httrack para salvar os arquivos e tentar subir os arquivos na hostinger, mas não deu certo também. e estou desamparada, não sei mais com quem pedir ajuda